# How to interpret the residual function in functional linear regression?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, statistics

When I reading the

> Functional Data Analysis

Writen by J.O. Ramsay B.W. Silverman.

At page 229, the author use the formula below to explain what is functional linear model,

$Prec_{mg}(t)=\mu(t)+\alpha_g(t)+\varepsilon_{mg}(t)$

And then the author said, $\varepsilon_{mg}(t)$ is the residual function.

I was confused that if we can use a function to specify the uncertainty, there should be no error then. I can not understand this point. Who can help me to explain this?

Comment: The error function could be distributed according to some process like a Gaussian process. You have that for each $g$ $Prec_{mg}(t)$ is $\mu(t) + \alpha_g(t)$, but the $m$'th observation is distorted by some random function $\epsilon_{mg}(t)$, so what you actually observe is the true function distorted with some random "functional noise".

Comment: Thank you so much.